# How to use one method to show a view and the same method to return resource collection Laravel/Vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a Vue component that uses Laravel Api data to show in the template. I have a CustomerController which uses the index() method to return the collection of CustomerResource which I used to create the API. I need that method also to show the view. How do I show the index.blade.php when the index method of CustomerController is used for API. If u have any questions about this problem ask me in the comment.

**Customer Controller**

```
   public function index() {
       return CustomerResource::collection(Customer::all());
   }
```

**api.php**

```
    Route::middleware('api')->prefix('v1')->group(function() {
        Route::apiResource('/customers', CustomerController::class);
    });
```

**index.blade.php**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
        <all-customers></all-customers>
    @endsection
```

**AllCustomers.vue**

```
    <template>
        <div class="customers">
            <div class="main-panel">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-12 text-right">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <!-- <router-link class="btn" :to="{ name: 'AddCustomer'}">Add New</router-link > -->
                                </a>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <button class="btn">Import</button>
                                </a>
                                <!-- <downloadExcel class = "btn btn-default"
                  :data   = "json_data"
                  :fields = "json_fields"
                  worksheet = "My Worksheet"
                  name    = "customers.xls">
                    Export
                </downloadExcel> -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
                  <h4 class="card-title ">All Customers</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead class=" text-primary">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="(customer,index) in customers" :key="index">
                          <td>
                            {{ customer.id }}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            {{ customer.name }}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            {{ customer.email }}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            {{ customer.phone }}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            {{ customer.address }}
                          </td>
                          <!-- <td>
                            <router-link :to="{name: 'EditCustomer'}">
                              <span class="material-icons">edit</span>
                            </router-link>
                              <span class="material-icons">delete</span>
                          </td> -->
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import JsonExcel from 'vue-json-excel'
    export default {
        name:'AllCustomers',
        components:{
            downloadExcel: JsonExcel
        },
        data(){
            return{
                customers:[],
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            axios
            .get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/customers')
            .then(response=> this.customers = response.data.data)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: why would you show the index.blade if you used the api ? ,, choose one , do you want to check for json and respond with either the collection or the blade ?

Answer (score 1):

you want to return the index.blade with the collection that you can get from the component .

### return the view with data and make the call to the same method

test the type of request , if the request wants json then give it only the collection if not then return a view . thats how you can return a view preloaded with the data and still benifit from the api in your vue js

```
   public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $customers = CustomerResource::collection(Customer::all());
           
       if($request->wantsJason()) {     // this will be called by the vue component
               return response()->json([
                      'customers' => $customers
               ],200)
        }

        // this will be trigger if a full http request sent (on site load)
        return view('index')->with('customers',$customers)
    }
```

#### OPTION 1 : acccess blade props in your vue template .

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content') // here you can use @if , @foreach , @can etc...
 <all-customers inline-template :customers='@json($customers)'> //passing customers as vue prop
 </all-customers>
```

**AllCustomers.vue**

```
<template> [ your code ...] </template>
<script>
    import JsonExcel from 'vue-json-excel'
    export default {
        name:'AllCustomers',
        props : ['customers']
        components:{
            downloadExcel: JsonExcel
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### **OPTION 2** inline-templates

if you are going to mix blade and vuejs than single file component (SFC) is not a good solution since you are going to use the laravel route and a whole page that contains only the vue tag is not optimal in reacting with vuejs using laravel functionalities like guards , loops and conditions

**solution** is [vue inline-template](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/inline-template-attribute.html) this will help you take advantage of both laravel functionalities and vuejs reactivity and ajax requests

**index.blade.php** *pass blade props as vue props*

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content') // here you can use @if , @foreach , @can etc...
 <all-customers inline-template :customers='@json($customers)'> //passing customers as vue prop
    <div class="customers">
        <div class="main-panel">
        <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-12 text-right">
                <a href="#">
                  <!-- <router-link class="btn" :to="{ name: 'AddCustomer'}"> 
                    Add New
                  </router-link > -->
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <button class="btn">Import</button>
                </a>
                <!-- <downloadExcel
                  class   = "btn btn-default"
                  :data   = "json_data"
                  :fields = "json_fields"
                  worksheet = "My Worksheet"
                  name    = "customers.xls">
                    Export
                </downloadExcel> -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
                  <h4 class="card-title ">All Customers</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead class=" text-primary">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="(customer,index) in customers" :key="index">
                          <td>
                            {{ customer.id }}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            {{ customer.name }}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            {{ customer.email }}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            {{ customer.phone }}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            {{ customer.address }}
                          </td>
                          <!-- <td>
                            <router-link :to="{name: 'EditCustomer'}">
                              <span class="material-icons">edit</span>
                            </router-link>
                              <span class="material-icons">delete</span>
                          </td> -->
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    </all-customers>
@endsection
```

**AllCustomers.vue**

```
<script>
    import JsonExcel from 'vue-json-excel'
    export default {
        name:'AllCustomers',
        props : ['customers']
        components:{
            downloadExcel: JsonExcel
        }
    }
</script>
```